# Installing tomcat 6 and mysql server on ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, tomcat, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have created an instance of ubuntu 10.04 lucid lynx on amazon ec2 cloud. Now I need to configure to run my web application which runs of java servlet and mysql 5.1. Since I am novice or newbie to this environment I need some help or reference material to do it. If you know such links or tutorial kindly let me know.

Thanks a ton

Comment: I have put together a few articles about [running Tomcat on Amazon Linux](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/tomcat-amazon-ec2-basic.html). Most of the content will apply to Ubuntu instances as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server tomcat6
```

That's really as complicated as it gets. Depending on how you do your webapp deployment, you'll want to install tomcat6-admin

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat6-admin
```

Config files can be found in

```
/etc/mysql
/etc/tomcat6
/etc/default/tomcat6.
```

Start and stop servers using

```
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 start|stop
/etc/init.d/mysql start|stop
```

Comment: I tried to install the tomcat6 using sudo apt-get install tomcat6 but the server hanged up and I am not able to kill the process now I am not able to anything.

Comment: You should be able to ctl-C the process. If that does not work, try ctl-Z, bg, kill -9 %1.

Comment: You may want to start with a 'sudo apt-get update' then a 'sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: I am not able to get the $ prompt to kill the process and I tried sudo apt-get update also but when I posted the same question on ubuntu forms and also AWS forms I got following replies check this links http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1708700 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=230776

Comment: I've noticed the micro instances on amazon are sometimes unable to cope with certain installations. What's worth trying is installing everything on a small size instance, making an image of the result, then running that up on the micro.